# Devise issues with soft-deleted Records. Any idea, how to fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, soft-delete, devise-confirmable

I'm using **discard** gem for **Soft** deletion. Once user gets Soft-Deleted, user can still receive forget password emails. Because Devise password controller does not care either its soft-deleted or not ?

I'm using following Devise modules, it seems, i may need to fix for all modules:-

- :confirmable,
- :recoverable,
- :timeoutable,
- :trackable
- :lockable
- :authenticatable

Though I'm able to fix login issue with authenticatable by overriding `find_for_authentication` method in user model, but it doesn't seem to be working with other Devise modules.

Any Idea, how i can fix soft-deletion issues with Devise ?

I'm using **devise(4.6.2), discard (1.0.0), Rails 5.1.6.2**

Answer (score 1):

You could use a default scope, ex:

```
class User
  ...
  default_scope -> { kept }
  ...
end
```

Other discard scopes like discarded and with_discarded should keep working since they operate on the same column (discard_column), so they would override the default scope. That way, there's no need to override any of devise methods

Comment: its already in my mind but I do not want to use default_scope due to some code dependencies in the application. is there any other setting in devise which i can use for soft-deletion

Answer (score 1):

Finally I'm able to fix it by overriding following method in user.rb. any one else, if facing the same issue, can fix it in following way:

```
# Override to add condition to ignore soft deleted users
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(conditions, opts = {})
  opts.reverse_merge!(discarded_at: nil)

  super
 end
```